# How to push build time from github actions to ELK or any server?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have been working on a project in which i need to track the build time of the application when i make a commit. How can we push the build time data to a server ?

Answer (score -1):

Reliza Hub (disclaimer I'm working on the tool) - provides build time analytics among other things. Just setup project per Getting Started guide here - https://docs.relizahub.com/guide/#description (this one already uses GitHub Actions).

Here is sample GitHub Actions integration script for docker images which includes sending build time data: https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-hub-integrations/blob/master/github-actions/dockerBuild.yml

In theory if you modify the script, you could similar data to your own platform such as ELK.

One note though that build time in this case does not include the time it takes for GitHub Actions to set up build environment.

After setting everything up you would get build time analytics chart in the project analytics which looks as following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5mqB.png

Alternatively, you can stream build time metadata elsewhere (suck as ELK) using similar principles as in sample integration yaml referenced above.